# Position in the list after a using a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I want to generate a list after using a function. In this list the original position is important.

```
listA = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, {6, 1}, {7, 2},
         {8, 7}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}};
```

The position is the first row (or field in each record). The position can be a number or a dataobject.

In this example I use the function BinList.

```
BinLists[listA[[All, 2]], 1]
```

which gives the output:

> {{}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3}, {}, {5}, {6}, {7}}

The desired output is:

> {{{},0}, {{{1, 1},1}, {{3, 1},1},{{6, 1}},1}, {{{2, 2},2},{{4, 2},2},{{7, 2}},2},{ {5,3},3}, {{},4}, {{10, 5},5}, {{9, 6},6},{{8, 7},7}}

In the desired output I know the Bin-class and the original position. So the combination '{6,1}' belongs to de 1-class en is the 6 position of the original list.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want - does the original list always have the first column going from `1` to `n`?
And would something like `GroupBy[listA, Last]` work for you? The output format is slightly different, but should be able to easily extract everything from there. If this is not good enough, can you explain what exactly you need to do with the list afterwards? Your output format seems quite complicated...

Comment: The first element gives always position, like a date. In this example I use 'BinList' as a smart way to create classifications of the list with numbers. When I use BinList[ListA[[All, 2]],.5] I get another grouping of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `{3, 1.1}` to test for realistic data.

```
listA = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1.1}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, {6, 1},
   {7, 2}, {8, 7}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}};

u = BinLists[listA[[All, 2]], 1]
```

> {{}, {1, 1.1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3}, {}, {5}, {6}, {7}}

```
out = Module[{z = listA, t = {}, s = 0, w, y},
 Function[v, w = {};
   (y = FirstCase[z, {_, #}];
      z = DeleteCases[z, y];
      AppendTo[w, {y, s}]) & /@ v;
   AppendTo[t, w /. {} -> {{}, s}];
   s++] /@ u;
 t /. {{{a_, b_}, c_}} :> {{a, b}, c}]
```

> {{{}, 0}, {{{1, 1}, 1}, {{3, 1.1}, 1}, {{6, 1}, 1}}, {{{2, 2}, 
>      2}, {{4, 2}, 2}, {{7, 2}, 2}}, {{5, 3}, 3}, {{}, 4}, {{10, 5}, 
>     5}, {{9, 6}, 6}, {{8, 7}, 7}}

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired output, but I'm not sure how the "xbins" argument should be chosen because `∞` doesn't work.

```
Replace[MapIndexed[{#, First[#2] - 1} &, #, {2}], {a_} -> a, {1}] &[
   First[BinLists[listA, 123123123, 1] /. {} -> {{}}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, {#, k} & /@ v], GroupBy[listA, Round@*Last]]
(* {{{{1, 1}, 1}, {{3, 1.1}, 1}, {{6, 1}, 1}}, {{{2, 2}, 2}, {{4, 2}, 2}, {{7, 2}, 2}}, {{{5, 3}, 3}}, {{{8, 7}, 7}}, {{{9, 6}, 6}}, {{{10, 5}, 5}}} *)
```

(Using the modified list from @ChrisDegnen). This solution omits empty bins, let me know if you need them.

Timing wise: Using `listA = Table[{i, RandomInteger[100]}, {i, 10000}];` & [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html):

- This solution: 0.02
- @ChrisDegnen's solution: 8.0
- @Coolwater's solution: 0.035

Comment: Can you suggest what to do if I want to use the function BinLists[listA[[All, 2]], .5]

Comment: You can adjust the bin width using the second parameter of `Round`. For `0.5` wide bins, this means `GroupBy[listA,Round[#2,0.5]&]` (or `GroupBy[listA,Round[#,0.5]&@*Last]]`).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Using `BinLists` as the third argument of `HistogramList` to get both bin limits and the contents of each bin and organizing the results:

```
ClearAll[binListsAndLims, binListsAndLimsByCol, oneBin]
oneBin = Floor[Max[#] + #2, #2] - Ceiling[Min[#] - #2, #2]  + 2 #2 &;

binListsAndLims[d_, bspec_] := Module[{b = ReplacePart[{oneBin[#, 1]} & /@ Transpose[d],
     (-1) -> bspec]},
 Thread /@ (Transpose[{#2[[## &@@ConstantArray[1, Length[b] - 1]]], Most[#[[-1]]]}] & @@ 
   HistogramList[d, b, BinLists[d, ## & @@ Function[t, {#[[t]]}] /@ Range[Length@b]] &] /.
      {} -> {{}})]

binListsAndLimsByCol[d_, bspec_, col_] := Module[{r = Length[d[[1]]] - col}, 
  If[col == Length[d[[1]]], binListsAndLims[d, bspec], 
   Replace[binListsAndLims[RotateRight[#, r] & /@ d, 
     bspec], {a_List, b_} :> {RotateLeft[a, r], b}, {0, Infinity}]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
binListsAndLimsByCol[listA, {1}, 2]
```

> {{{{}, 0}},
>   {{{1, 1}, 1}, {{3, 1}, 1}, {{6, 1}, 1}},
>    {{{2, 2}, 2}, {{4, 2}, 2}, {{7, 2}, 2}},
>   {{{5, 3}, 3}},
>    {{{}, 4}},
>   {{{10, 5}, 5}},
>   {{{9, 6}, 6}},
>    {{{8, 7}, 7}}}

Use a different bin spec:

```
binListsAndLimsByCol[listA, {.5}, 2]
```

> {{{{}, 0.5}}, {{{1, 1}, 1.}, {{3, 1}, 1.}, {{6, 1}, 1.}}, {{{}, 
>      1.5}}, {{{2, 2}, 2.}, {{4, 2}, 2.}, {{7, 2}, 2.}}, {{{}, 
>      2.5}}, {{{5, 3}, 3.}}, {{{}, 3.5}}, {{{}, 4.}}, {{{}, 
>      4.5}}, {{{10, 5}, 5.}}, {{{}, 5.5}}, {{{9, 6}, 6.}}, {{{}, 
>      6.5}}, {{{8, 7}, 7.}}}

Bin by column 1:

```
binListsAndLimsByCol[listA, {1}, 1]
```

> {{{{}, 0}}, {{{1, 1}, 1}}, {{{2, 2}, 2}}, {{{3, 1}, 3}}, {{{4, 2}, 
>      4}}, {{{5, 3}, 5}}, {{{6, 1}, 6}}, {{{7, 2}, 7}}, {{{8, 7}, 
>      8}}, {{{9, 6}, 9}}, {{{10, 5}, 10}}}

With more than 2 columns:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
dd = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {20, 4}];
binListsAndLimsByCol[dd, {1}, 2]
```

> {{{{}, 0}}, {{{2, 1, 9, 2}, 1}, {{4, 1, 3, 7}, 1}, {{2, 1, 1, 7}, 
>      1}}, {{{6, 2, 4, 2}, 2}}, {{{8, 3, 8, 9}, 3}, {{7, 3, 8, 7}, 
>      3}, {{6, 3, 7, 8}, 3}, {{7, 3, 5, 2}, 3}}, {{{9, 4, 4, 8}, 
>      4}, {{3, 4, 4, 9}, 4}}, {{{6, 5, 8, 6}, 5}, {{2, 5, 6, 1}, 
>      5}, {{9, 5, 6, 7}, 5}}, {{{}, 6}}, {{{8, 7, 9, 6}, 
>      7}, {{2, 7, 5, 9}, 7}}, {{{4, 8, 4, 7}, 8}, {{8, 8, 3, 9}, 
>      8}, {{9, 8, 9, 7}, 8}}, {{{7, 9, 7, 2}, 9}, {{4, 9, 4, 5}, 9}}}

**Original answer:**

```
Table[Thread[{Pick[#, #[[All, 2]], i] /. {} -> {{}}, i}], {i, 0, Max[#[[All, 2]]]}]&@listA
```

> {{{}, 0}, {{{1, 1}, 1}, {{3, 1}, 1}, {{6, 1}, 1}}, {{{2, 2}, 
>      2}, {{4, 2}, 2}, {{7, 2}, 2}}, {{{5, 3}, 3}}, {{}, 
>     4}, {{{10, 5}, 5}}, {{{9, 6}, 6}}, {{{8, 7}, 7}}}

If you have to use `BinLists` as input:

```
bl = MapIndexed[If[# == {} , #2[[1]] - 1, #]&, BinLists[listA[[All, 2]], 1]] 
pick = Pick[listA, listA[[All, 2]], #] & /@ Range[0, Max[listA[[All, 2]]]]
thread = If[Head[#[[2]]] === List, Thread @ #, #]&;
thread /@ Transpose @ {pick, bl}
```

> same result